# Distributed Shared Memory in .NET

Tags: .net, distributed, shared-memory

Are there any existing libraries/frameworks/products for a [distributed shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_shared_memory) system implemented in .NET, or easily accessible from .NET clients?

Googling gives some links to academic papers, but I couldn't find any real implementations.

Note: I am most interested in something that runs on a LAN, not in "cloud".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx) aka [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx)?

> A new Microsoft project, code-named Velocity, provides a distributed, in-memory cache. Velocity enables you to create scalable, available, high-performance applications by exposing a unified view of distributed memory for client application consumption.

Comment: It's called Windows AppFabric now.

Answer (score 0):

There are many products that support .net c# client but are written in java language. i would advice you to check Oracle Coherence, VMware Gemfire and Gigaspaces XAP. they have have a .net clients. Gigaspaces also offer a combination of application server messaging and data grid all running on .net.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Coherence supports .NET clients via a number of APIs & technologies:

- IIS session management support
- REST APIs for data access
- .NET memcache client support
- .NET native (C#) Coherence API

It also supports native Java and native C++. Via the REST and memcache protocol support, it covers basically every platform & language.

Regarding "shared memory", Coherence has applications in production with 25+TB of "shared memory" data.

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the opinions or views of my employer.*